# Javascript: how to pass non-string or number data to a function invoked via eval?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have the following eval to invoke function F.

```
eval('F()');
```

Here is F's definition, which should take a DOM or JQuery object (obtained via selector such as $('#move'))

```
function F(dom_element) {
  alert('in F');
}
```

I tried the following and it is not working:

```
eval('F(' + dom_element +')');
```

I am unable to find a solution for passing a object (non-string or number) data to F. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks and regards!

**----------------- reply to "why do you eval it" -----------------**

I have a generic modal window on links that do some deletion work. For example:

```
<a href="#" class="link-confirm-action" data-action="deleteRecordTypeA">delete</a>
```

In the above, class "link-confirm-action" will invoke the modal window to get confirmation before doing actual deletion. Within the modal window's javascript, I have the following when a user decides to proceed:

eval($(this).attr('data-action'));

Actual deletion varies depending on links. I could have deleteRecordTypeA, deleteRecordTypeB, etc. They are all functions. These functions need to know their environment in order to do meaningful backend Ajax work and front-end DOM manipulation.

Thanks!

Comment: at first - why do you need to `eval` it?

Comment: `evil()` should be avoided. This is a classic XY problem - what do you want to do in the first place? Also, if `F` is a function, why not just call it? `F.call(target, arg1, arg2...)` or `F.apply(target, arglist)` works famously with non-strings. Not to even mention `F(arg1, arg2...)` - so `F(dom_element)` or `F.call(this, dom_element)` should be sufficient for most purposes.

Comment: The use of eval can only be justified if you are dynamically generating code, if that is the case then you must accept the fact that you gonna have to deal with strings, if that's not the case then I am pretty sure your problem can be solved more efficiently using a different approach, why don't you explain so we can give you ideas?

Comment: Demetrius Amadeus, I am using eval to call different functions depending on context. I explained why I need to do this in the post. Hope you agree with me about using eval in my situation. Cheers!

Comment: @curious1: No, I do not agree. The non-`evil` way to do this is have a lookup table, `actions = { deleteRecordTypeA: deleteRecordTypeA, deleteRecordTypeB: deleteRecordTypeB }` and then invoke `actions[$(this).attr('data-action')].call(this)`. It is a bit more wordy, but way safer - and faster in execution. (Obviously, you can even inline the functions, as in `actions = { deleteRecordTypeA: function() { ... }, deleteRecordTypeB: function() { ... } }` Seriously, 99% of cases where people think `evil` is appropriate can be solved in a different and better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eval() will just execute the string as normal javascript code, so here it will call your function which I think you don't need to put it in eval. 
If you want the function to take an object such as DOM element, then you could write the code of getting the element in the string before your function:

```
eval('var elem=document.getElementById("elem_id");F(elem);');
```

Comment: grape_mao, thanks for chiming in! Your solution works nicely!